# TF 2.0: How to convert Tensor("mul_1:0", shape=(1000, 64), dtype=float32) to Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I use Tensorflow 2.0 and have a tensor `X` that I would like to process with Numpy.

If I print the tensor I get the following:

```
print(X) = 
Tensor("mul_1:0", shape=(1000, 64), dtype=float32)
```

I tried to convert the tensor to a numpy array using `X.numpy()` and `X.as_numpy()` which throws the following errors:

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'as_numpy'
```

How can I access the tensor's values?

EDIT:

When I use `print(type(X))` I get:

`<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>`

Comment: Do you have eager execution disabled?

Comment: @user3483203 No. But I also tried to use `tf.executing_eagerly()` right before `X.numpy()` which didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Please give a self-contained reproducible example, there is little we can tell from the information in the question.

Comment: what is your `X`? do it store any value or it's a placeholder and  tf 2.0 doesn't need eager execution

Comment: @ShubhamShaswat `X` is a Tensor. `print(X) = 
Tensor("mul_1:0", shape=(1000, 64), dtype=float32)`. There are no placeholders in TF 2.0, right?

Comment: what value you are passing to th  `X`

Comment: @ShubhamShaswat I am not sure what you mean. `X` is not a placeholder. It is the result of a `tf.matmul()` operation. It should be a tensor filled with numerical values. I do not pass anything to `X`

Comment: Is the function containing `X` (i.e., the function where `tf.matmul` is called) and the print statement decorated with `@tf.function`, or a part of a `tf.keras` layer's `call`?

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal The function that returns `X` is not decorated with `@tf.function` and does not use `tf.keras.layers`.

Comment: have you performed the the `tf.matmul()` operations with values?

Comment: @ShubhamShaswat Yes.

Answer (score 0):

You could try reproducing your problem in **Google Colab Environment** and/or Try **Updating** your **TensorFlow version** to the **latest** (2.1.0 as of now).

Here is a simulation of your scenario successfully executed as intended:

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x  
import tensorflow as tf  # TensorFlow 2.1.0

a  = tf.random.normal((5,5), seed = 26)  # Seed for Reproducibility
b  = tf.random.normal((5,5), seed = 26)

tf.linalg.matmul(a,b)  # Returns : <tf.Tensor: shape=(5, 5), dtype=float32, numpy= array([[-9.3171215e+00,  ...... 5.1605763e+00, 9.6334761e-01]], dtype=float32)>
tf.matmul(a,b)  # Returns value same as before
```